# How can know the "providers" column in symfony2 custom user provider

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am not able to find what are the other options for providers in Symfony security

e,g

This link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

says that

```
security:
    providers:
        webservice:
            id: webservice_user_provider
```

Now I know that id is the service id of the class which implements `UserProviderInterface`

But what is `webservice` here, how can I get it?

What is the diff between this code and the code above

```
providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User}
```

I am confused whether I need to use User as Entity there or `UserManager` which implements `UserProviderInterface` there

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a [step](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-service-for-the-user-provider). And second example is the configuration of `EntityUserProvider`.